# Electron: how to print all html content in pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, electron

I'm using Electron for my first project, i have to print a PDF file from my html.

What's in my code now:

```
    ipc.on('print-to-pdf', event => {
      const pdfPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'temp_pdf.pdf')

      const win = BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender)

      win.webContents.printToPDF({marginsType: 1, pageSize:'Tabloid'}, (error, data) => {
        if (error) return console.log(error.message)

        fs.writeFile(pdfPath, data, err => {
          if (err) return console.log(err.message)
          shell.openExternal('file://' + pdfPath)
        })
      })
    })

but when my app create .pdf file, the content is sliced in the second page.
Like that:
[Error pdf][1]
maybe it depends on the setting of the page size:

    win.webContents.printToPDF({marginsType: 1, pageSize:'Tabloid'}, (error, data) => {
        if (error) return console.log(error.message)
```

how can i fixed that?

**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ6tT.png**

Comment: what do you mean by "the content is sliced in the second page"?  can you provide a sample of what you're seeing?

Comment: I modified my question adding an image, you can see that the second page does not show all rest of content

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding this in my css:

```
@media print {
  body {
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
}
```

now the pdf is complete, showing all pages